# How do I simplify this sum of products expression into an easier sop form

Tags: digital-logic

'=Compliment

D=P'VST + PV'S'T + PV'ST'+ PV'ST + PVS'T' + PVS'T + PVST' + PVST
I'm having trouble simplifying this.

Comment: Have you tried K-maps?

Comment: The Maxterms can be easily found out from your expression here, and when you have the maxterms, you know the minterms too (The rest of them). Now, as @ChrisLaplante said, use K-maps for SOP simplification.

Answer (score 5):

For a beginner this is best done with a 4-variable K-map.

See here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map
http://www.ece.rice.edu/~kmram/elec326/Notes/notes-326-set5.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit rusty on these things but this should help as a start: -

P'VST + PV'S'T + PV'ST'+ PV'ST + PVS'T' + PVS'T + PVST' + PVST becomes

(P'VST + PVST) + P(V'S'T + V'ST' + V'ST + VS'T' + VS'T + VST') which becomes

VST + P(S'T + ST' + V'ST + VS'T') etc..

Answer (score 0):

If we break the terms apart, we have 8 (P'VST -> 1000), 6 (PV'S'T -> 0110), 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, and 0. From those we can combine (via [Q-M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm), which combines values with single-bit differences):

3, 2, 1, and 0 (00XX -> PV)
5, 4, 1, and 0 (0X0X -> PS)
6, 4, 2, and 0 (0XX0 -> PT)
8 and 0 (X000 -> VST)

Putting those together we get PV + PS + PT + VST, which can be simplified even further if desired.

Comment: I don't think this answer is very useful to a beginner.